# Django returns duplicates but same query from dbshell return only one record

Tags: sql, django

I dont understand why Django returns duplicates in code below, can somebody explain it?
thanks.

```
qs = PropTelephone.objects.filter(reference=91811, tel_number__isnull=False).exclude(tel_number='').values_list('tel_number', flat=True).distinct()

print qs
[u'0410224291', u'0410224291']

print qs.query
SELECT DISTINCT `PROP_TELEPHONE`.`TEL_NUMBER` FROM `PROP_TELEPHONE` WHERE (`PROP_TELEPHONE`.`TEL_NUMBER` IS NOT NULL AND `PROP_TELEPHONE`.`REFERENCE` = 91811  AND NOT (`PROP_TELEPHONE`.`TEL_NUMBER` = '' ))
```

query launched from dbshell returns only one record

```
+-------------------------------+
| TEL_NUMBER                    |
+-------------------------------+
| 0410224291                    |
+-------------------------------+
```

so why django returns for such query two same records?
ofcourse in DB exists two records, with different values in other columns.
but distinct for column tel_number should return only one IMHO.

Comment: Do you have `unique_together` set on the model? That could explain the issue.

Comment: No, `unique_together` is not set on that model.

Comment: Same result for `print qs.order_by()` too, right?

Comment: yes, same `print qs.order_by()`
`[u'0410224291', u'0410224291']`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quote from documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct : 
"Similarly, if you use a values() query to restrict the columns selected, the columns used in any order_by() (or default model ordering) will still be involved and may affect uniqueness of the results."

Is it possible you have default model ordering for your PropTelephone containing more columns than just tel_number?

Comment: that `qs.query` have no `ORDER BY` clause, so i think this is not such case